# Breadcrumb trail resulting in duplicate URLs

Tags: seo, ecommerce, breadcrumbs

In an eCommerce site, I have products that can be under more than 1 category, this causes multiple URLs for the same product. The reason being, is that if a user clicks on category A then on product A the breadcrumb trail shows a link back to category A.

The only issue is, in order to ensure that the breadcrumb truly reflects the path the user has chosen I have included the category id in the link to the product, i.e:

```
/product?id=10&cat=5
```

...and because products can have more than one category there might be:

```
/product?id=10&cat=6
```

However, the usual URL for a product would be:

```
/product?id=10
```

This obviously means I'm potentially having more than 1 URL for each product.

Is there a better way to ensure the correct breadcrumb trail or is this really not that much of an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem because it potentially will cause duplicate content issues with Google. But you can just use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to indicate the one URL you want to represent that page. That easily solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something similar (breadcrumbs are really only for the user, not for search.)  I would store it in a session variable instead of in the URL.

I don't know what language you are using, but i use VB.NET so it's simply:

```
session("category") = 6
```

Then read it back in when loading the product page.